# Do you indent a text message at the beginning of a chapter?

Tags: style

I would like to start a chapter with a text message.

I believe based on the style guides I've read that you should indent text messages, but how about if they are at the start of a chapter?

Usually you don't indent the first line of a chapter, so I was wondering if anyone had any advice about what to do in this situation?

Comment: I think The Hunt for Red October used this device extensively. 
I searched for "epigraph", but the search results seem more geared toward placing a literary quote at the beginning of a book.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a screenshot of the text message or messages. Doing so will give a more direct impression of seeing the message on a phone. The next best thing might be to place it in a text box (with rounded corners) to suggest that the text is being displayed a screen.

Answer (score 1):

If your book is going to be published by a traditional publishing house, they'll format it however they like.

If your book is going to be self-published, you can format it however *you* like. Go ahead and break convention for one chapter if you need to. I promise you won't be punished for it. :)